# How to allow Infinite Scrolling through "Views Load More" module with waypoints?

Tags: views

I am trying to achieve infinite scrolling for my view results in Drupal.

Now It could have been easier if I could use `Views Infinite Scroll` module but I couldn't use as it doesn't allow Views Ajax. Since I am using filters that heavily rely on AJAX, I am out of luck for using this module.

As I read, there is another option through `Views Load More` module, but it can only allow infinite scroll through `Waypoints`. This is where my problem lies as I am unable to understand how to use waypoints with Views Load More module.

I'll be super grateful if you could assist me in this.

This is Waypoints code from their site:-

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('#waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually really easy to do with standard Views and [jQuery.autopager](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autopager/) in your theme.

The most important part is using the correct classes, I can't find my working example at the moment, but it should look something like:

```
$.autopager({
  // where contents would be appended.
  // use "appendTo" or "insertBefore"
  appendTo: '.views-content',

  // a selector that matches a element of next page link
  link: '.pagination .next a:first',

  // a selector that matches page contents
  content: '.views-row',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try for [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module as now, its in stable `8.x-1.3` version.

Comment: Hello for 8.x1.3 gives  error like info file is not exits. can you please provide solutions for that.

Comment: @DineshBhojvani: Can you please paste your error here.

Comment: ajax.js?v=7.54:546 Uncaught TypeError: wrapper[method] is not a function I am getting this error is it due to in my html there is not any div has wrapper class.